# Bootstrap z-index issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing to show panel with max-height but it doesn't work properly.

Z-Index is not working normally.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <img src="image">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Css codes`:

```
panel-heading{
    text-align: center;
    max-height:200px;
    z-index: -9999;
}
.panel-heading img{
    z-index: -9999;
}
.panel-body{
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

So image is showing like this:

[image]

The image is supposed to be behind the panel. I mean it contains body. It shouldn't be like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

If I understand correctly, you want the height of the image to be cut off after `200px` since that is the `max-height` assigned to `.panel-heading`. Please try this:

```css
.panel-heading {
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <img width=" 100%" src="http://placehold.it/350x750">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image that I've used has a height of `750px` but since I am using `overflow: hidden` on `.panel-heading`, the height of the image gets cut off after `200px`.